# XCode precompiled OpenCL crashes on different Mac OS versions and alternating CPU/GPU

Tags: xcode, opencl

I've got a very strange problem:

One of my projects uses OpenCL and is compiled with the following options in XCode:

```
OPENCL_ARCHS : i386 x86_64 gpu_32 gpu_64
OPENCL_COMPILER_VERSION : CL1.2
```

However, when I run it under 10.8.5 it crashes when I use CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU and when it is 10.9.5 it crashes on the CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU. But the other way around is respectively working.

All I am trying is to run a empty test kernel:

```
kernel void InitBlocks(global float* pointless) {

}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    gcdQueue = gcl_create_dispatch_queue(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_XPU, NULL);
    cl_ndrange range = {
        1,
        {0, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 0}
    };
    dispatch_sync(gcdQueue, ^{
        InitBlocks_kernel(&range, Nil);
    });
}
```

It does not mater whenever I pass arguments or not, run the kernel later or actually do some calculations inside. It always crashes in the invocation:

```
// Block function
void (^InitBlocks_kernel)(const cl_ndrange *ndrange, cl_float* unneccessary) =
^(const cl_ndrange *ndrange, cl_float* unneccessary) {
  int err = 0;
  cl_kernel k = bmap.map[0].kernel;
  if (!k) {
    initBlocks();
    k = bmap.map[0].kernel;
  }
  if (!k)
    gcl_log_fatal("kernel InitBlocks does not exist for device");
  kargs_struct kargs;
  gclCreateArgsAPPLE(k, &kargs);
  err |= gclSetKernelArgMemAPPLE(k, 0, unneccessary, &kargs);
  gcl_log_cl_fatal(err, "setting argument for InitBlocks failed");
  err = gclExecKernelAPPLE(k, ndrange, &kargs);
  gcl_log_cl_fatal(err, "Executing InitBlocks failed"); // <---- Here, err = -45
  gclDeleteArgsAPPLE(k, &kargs);
};
```

I think it means that it could not load the machine code for the specific target device / platform.

But I know it could run on CPU as well as GPU because I tested both on the same hardware with two different Mac OS X versions (boot options). And each version only supports one target device. What am I doing wrong? Is it my source code or the compiler options?

Hope I provided enough information and someone got a clue about it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue w/ the precompiled + automatic Xcode integration stuff.  Apple doesn't seem to care to fix this though, their own sample code crashes as well.  The workaround is to compile your source at runtime.

Comment: Nice to know, thanks. Will it be fixed sometime, like in 10.10 or is it still broken?

Comment: I haven't checked to see if it's fixed in 10.10 or not yet, sorry.